# Magento API Call 503s

Tags: magento, http-status-code-503

Everything in my Magento store is working ok, except for a route I created that calls the API:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('SOAPCLIENTURL');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
$proxy->customerCustomerCreate($sessionId, array(
    'email' => $email,
    'firstname' => '',
    'lastname' => '',
    'password' => $password,
    'website_id' => 7,
    'store_id' => 7
));
```

When I comment out these lines, the route works fine. Any ideas why this 503s the page and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code block that's causing your problem is a request to an external API that could fail for numerous reasons.  The way you'd fix this is to monitor your server and Magento error and exception logs for errors, take a look at the error, and then fix the problem (or post the specific error to a site like this and ask for help).

You could also try running the above code snippet outside of a Magento context (in a stand along script) and see what sort of error you get.

If errors aren't showing up then you need to research how to setup your system for proper error handling.

Also, if you're setting up a Magento route and making an API call **into the same system**, there's no reason to use the SOAP or XML-RPC layer.  Each Magento API section has a corresponding PHP object that contains all the logic.   The above method is equivalent to

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer_api_v2')->create(array(...));
```

With the real PHP class being at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api/V2.php
```

and the `create` method defined at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php
```